# Reload body items once data from service layer loads in swiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I'm new to the swiftUI, looking for a way to refresh view once service data retrieved. What I want is, once page loads, -or before page loads- I want to call fillUI function so I can retrieve parsed json data from service layer, with that data I want to refresh this code block so my foreach block works with data I have:

```
                            VStack(spacing:15 ) {
                                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                                    VStack {
                                            ForEach(0..<5) { i in
                                                MeetingCellView(meetingData: meetingListData?.get(at: i) )
                                                    .frame(width: 340, height: 150)
                                                    .padding(.horizontal)
                                                    
                                            }.frame(width: 350)

                                    }
                                }.frame(width: 350)
                            }
```

In UIKit, i was able to solve these issues with a way like loading and retrieving all the data first, then showing the view itself with a data. For swiftUI what is the best approach to do that?

Here is the full code of my related view body. I had searched internet but couldn't find the one yet.

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    @State var username: String = ""
    @State var meetingCode: String = ""
    @State var data: GetUserDetailModel? = nil
    @State var meetingListData: [Datum]? = nil
    @State var requestLoaded = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            VStack {
                Image("home.background")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(maxHeight: 338)
                Spacer()
                
                ZStack {
                    VStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                            .padding(.top, -20)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false)
                    {
                        //MARK: - ScrollView Start
                        VStack {
                            HStack(spacing: 13.0) {
                                NavigationLink(destination: CreateMeetingView()) {
                                    
                                    
                                    ZStack {
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.935, green: 0.914, blue: 0.957))
                                        VStack(spacing: 18) {
                                            HStack {
                                                Image("icon.camera")
                                                Spacer()
                                            }
                                            HStack {
                                                Text("New Meeting")
                                                    .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.476, green: 0.228, blue: 0.701))
                                                    .font(.custom("inter-semibold", size: 15))
                                                Spacer()
                                            }
                                            
                                        }.padding(.horizontal, 15)
                                        
                                    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, idealHeight: 101)
                                        .padding(.leading, 25)
                                }
                                
                                NavigationLink(destination: Text("there"))
                                {
                                    ZStack {
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.897, green: 0.939, blue: 0.978))
                                        VStack(spacing: 18) {
                                            HStack {
                                                Image("icon.calendar")
                                                Spacer()
                                            }
                                            HStack {
                                                Text("Schedule Now")
                                                    .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.038, green: 0.525, blue: 0.917))
                                                    .font(.custom("inter-semibold", size: 15))
                                                Spacer()
                                            }
                                            
                                        }.padding(.horizontal, 15)
                                        
                                    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, idealHeight: 101)
                                        .padding(.trailing, 25)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                        VStack {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Upcoming Meetings")
                                    .font(.custom("inter-semibold", size: 17))
                                    .padding(.leading, 25)
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            
                            ZStack {
                                
                                VStack(spacing: 30) {
                                    HStack {
                                        Image("upcoming.calendar")
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("You do not have a upcoming meeting.")
                                            .font(.custom("inter-regular", size: 15))
                                            .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.692, green: 0.692, blue: 0.692))
                                    }
                                }.hidden()
                                    .padding(.vertical, 46)
                                
                                
                                VStack(spacing:15 ) {
                                    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                                        VStack {
                                                ForEach(0..<5) { i in
                                                    MeetingCellView(meetingData: meetingListData?.get(at: i) )
                                                        .frame(width: 340, height: 150)
                                                        .padding(.horizontal)
                                                        
                                                }.frame(width: 350)
    
                                        }
                                    }.frame(width: 350)
                                }
                                
                            }
                                .padding(.horizontal ,15)
                            
                        }.padding(.top, 25)
                            .padding(.bottom, 100)
                        
                        //MARK:  ScrollView End
                    }
                }
            }.ignoresSafeArea()
            
            
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Image("splash.logo")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(maxWidth: 100, maxHeight: 20)
                        .padding(.leading, 24)
                    Spacer()
                    Image("icon.profile")
                        .padding(.trailing,25)
                    
                    
                }
                VStack(spacing: 10.0) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Good Morning,")
                            .font(.custom("inter-semibold", size: 13))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text(username)
                            .font(.custom("inter-semibold", size: 22))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    
                    
                }.padding(.leading, 24)
                
                ZStack {
                    Color.white
                    VStack(spacing: 10.0) {
                        
                        HStack {
                            Text("Join Meeting")
                                .font(.custom("inter-semibold", size: 13))
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        
                        HStack {
                            TextField("Enter meeting code", text: $meetingCode)
                                .font(.custom("inter-regular", size: 15))
                                .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                        }
                    }.padding(.horizontal, 15)
                    
                    
                }
                .cornerRadius(6)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 75.0)
                .padding(.horizontal, 25.0)
                .padding(.top, 30)
                
                
                Spacer()
            }.hiddenNavigationBarStyle()
            
        }
            .onAppear(perform: fillUI)
            
            
            
    }
    func fillUI() {
        username = data?.givenName ?? "error"
        Network.meetingList {meetings in
            //print(meetings)
            meetingListData = meetings?.data
            requestLoaded = true
            
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are familiar with UIKit look at the SwiftUI View like the storyboard and an ObservableObject like the ViewController. When a Published variable is updated SwiftUI automatically reloads the View. Have your service layer update the Published variable. There is way to much code in your example, if you want more specific help try narrowing it down to the least amount of code needed to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thank you @loremipsum for your answer. I have checked published logic for it. So I have model that json data getting parsed there, also I have this view. Can you guide me how to use published, observable object definition here?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Answer (score 0):

We use [`task(priority:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(priority:_:)) for that, .e.g

```
List {
    ForEach(meetings) { meeting in
        MeetingView(meeting: meeting)
    }
}
.navigationTitle(loaded ? "Meetings" : "Loading...")
.task {
    loaded = false
    meetings = await Meeting.fetchAll()
    loaded = true
}
```

Also your `body` is far too large and you have too many `@State`. Break it up into subviews and try to only have 1 or 2 `@State` per `View`.

Comment: Thanks for reply @malhal, do I need to use this for body closure or for that case for foreach closure?

Comment: Usually it is on a List closure